# How to make Foundation and Pattern Lab, work for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, twig, zurb-foundation, patternlab.io

How to combine console Gulp with Twig? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out Starterkits.
See this [basic documentation](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/wiki/Importing-Starterkits) about them.

The main point is that a starterkit is a collection of frontend assets and patterns, which can be plugged into Pattern Lab.

They usually consiste of the following:

`_annotations/
    _data/
    _meta/
    _patterns/
    css/
    fonts/
    images/
    js/
    favicon.ico`

css, fonts, images, js will contain the Foundation library code you care about, if it applies.

`_patterns/` is where you can start building out twig code files with the right classes to realize your design.

`_meta/` should also contain your header and footer twig snippet to be included with every pattern.

If you want something to start from, you can probably augment the [existing drupal startkit](https://github.com/pattern-lab/starterkit-twig-drupal-minimal) over on Github.

Good luck!

Comment: Ho Brian Thanks forse your answer! Thank you for describing every detail useful to using PatternLab

Comment: Glad to hear it! Since you are new to Stack Overflow, if you like or accept answers, don't forget to "upvote" and/or "mark as answer" the response you like the most. It helps other users find the most helpful content.